# Im trying to make it where the bot will tell you to specify a member to mute if they dont specify it. How do i do that? I tried to but it doesnt work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Mute code below. If a mod doesnt specify what member to mute, how can the bot tell them that? Thanks!

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
   
    if member.id == ctx.author.id:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, YOU HAVE BEEN STOPPED BY ME YAY, you can't mute yourself!")
        return

    if discord.Member == None:
      await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, HEY you nugget, you need to specify who you want to mute!")
      return    

    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='muted')

    if role in ctx.guild.roles:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Muted", description=f"Offender: {member.mention} has been muted until further notice!", color=0x00FFFF)
        embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=f'{reason}', inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Moderator", value=f'{ctx.author.name}', inline=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
      await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Make sure your muted role is called `muted` in all lowercase! Then try again.")
```

Comment: "I tried to but it doesnt work" Please read [ask]. This isn't a sufficient description of the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel There wasn't a problem but thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought was right, but you need to approach it a little differently.

**Take a look at the following code:**

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    if member.id == ctx.message.author.id:
        await ctx.send("You can't mute yourself")
    if member:
        # Do what you want if the member was given
```

- What we only did is work with `if` statements.
- If you want you can also use `return await` so the bot will no longer proceed.

You can also build in an error handler for different things. **Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("No member given")
```

- You have to put the code under the actual `mute` command code.

Comment: Thx for answering! I tried this and it still doesnt work, i wanted to test out if "if" worked so i changed the == in the `if member.id == ctx.author.id:` ans when i did that, THAT stopped working when i changed it to "if". Also, this is the code that i changed. `@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):

    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, HEY you nugget, please specify a member to mute!")
        return`

Comment: I made a new edit, does that work? You can also not work with `else` statements and simply do: `if member:`

Comment: I tried this and it still does not work. Everything else still does though.

Comment: *I tried this and it still does not work. Everything else still does though.* - What does that exactly mean? Any errors?

Comment: There are no errors.. when i just type >mute, the message, "specify a member" doesnt send. But when i try to mute myself or mute someone else, it still works fine.

Comment: THANK YOU It now works! I upvoted your answer 